# Vuex, Axios variable is undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import api from "./api_key";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    data: "",
    location: "New York"
  },
  mutations: {
    GET_DATA(state, data) {
      state.data = data;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getData({ commit }, state) {
      axios
       .get(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${
            state.location
          }&appid=${api}&units=metric&cnt=5`
        )
        .then(data => {
          commit("GET_DATA", data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {
    data(state) {
      return state.data;
    }
  }
});
```

I am working on Vue web application. For state management I decided to use vuex. My "location" and "api" variables are undefined in my Axios request address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access your current state in your action, you misplaced the `state` declaration in `getData`. It should be like this: `getData({ commit, state })`.

But yet, I don't understand why `api` is undefined. Besides that, be carefull on the `data` recuperation, it's more like this:

```
.then((response) => {
     if (response.data) {
         commit("GET_DATA", response.data);
     }
}
```

EDIT:
Your `api_key.js` file should contains something like this in order to work with the import you are using:

```
export default "my_api_key";
```

Comment: Not Axios. The api variable

Comment: How do you declare your api variable in your `./api_key`?

Comment: I forgot curly brackets. Fixed. Thank you very much

Comment: Okay, great! Good luck